# Using Netbeans 8.0.2 and want to use org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; how?

Tags: java, apache, netbeans

Specifically I want to use the `FileUtils.contentEquals(file1, file2)` method.

I've downloaded and extracted files to `C:\Users\Dov\commons-io-2.4-bin\commons-io-2.4`.

I added exactly that pathname to my Netbeans project `Librairies` folder but of course `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;` didn't compile.

What will make the program below compile?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import static org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.contentEquals;

public class CompareFileContents {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\Dov\\Docs\\desktop.ini");
        File file2 = new File("C:\\Users\\Dov\\Documents\\desktop.ini");

        System.out.println("test1.txt and test2.txt are the same: " +
                           contentEquals(file1, file2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Can you tell me where do you find the library? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on your project

Properties - Library - Compile tab - Add Jar/Folder and select the .jar File

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Abdullah. I also figured out that all I have to do is right click the `Libraries` folder in the `MrCopy` project folder and `Add jar...`.